# Set a new Parse server in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-server

I am porting my iOS app to a new parse server. Does anyone know how to set the server address in Objective-C? Every sample that I have found is in Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, 
you need to use **initializeWithConfiguration**

your code should look like the following:

```js
    [Parse initializeWithConfiguration: [ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock: ^ (id < ParseMutableClientConfiguration > _Nonnull configuration) {
      configuration.applicationId = "{APP_ID}";
      configuration.clientKey = "{CLIENT_KEY}";
      configuration.server = "{SERVER_URL}";
      configuration.localDatastoreEnabled = NO;
    }]];
```

to your question... the **configuration.server** is what you need.